# Mysql - Building the sum of values of different tables

Tags: mysql, outer-join

Suppose we have two tables taba and tabb

```
CREATE TABLE `taba` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `tabb` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

I would like to build the sum for identical IDs using a query that works in any constellation. This usually refers to the missing FULL OUTER JOIN issue in MySql, to be solved using the UNION workaround

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `sum` AS 
SELECT a.id, a.`value` + COALESCE(b.`value`,0) AS `mysum` 
FROM taba a 
LEFT JOIN tabb b ON a.id=b.id 
UNION
SELECT b.id, COALESCE(a.`value`,0) + b.`value` AS `mysum` 
FROM tabb b 
LEFT JOIN taba a ON a.id=b.id
```

Let us note this in a short form as

```
taba + tabb
```

Is there a generally working cooking recept for more than two summands, i.e.

```
taba + tabb + tabc
```

or do I have to solve it in the way of using "virtual brackets"?

```
(taba + tabb) + tabc
```

Or is there a better way at all for an abritrary number of summands?

EDIT: An idea may be to skip the UNION construct AND use 'something' (a subquery?) which provides the union set of all IDs and 0 as value AS the first summand. In this case, COALESCE AND LEFT JOIN would be sufficient.

Subqueries do not cope with views in MySql, but this could be worked around.

Comment: Do you want the sum from all tables for *all* ids or a particular id when you run the query?

Comment: for all IDs, i.e. if an ID is defined in any table, the value must show up in the sum query/view.

Comment: amow's answer seems spot on to me but if you're still struggling, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
select id,sum(value)
from (
select id, value from taba
union all
select id, value from tabb) t
group by id
```

If you have multiple tables can be select into the same format, just put them in the sub clause and union them all together using `union all`.

Comment: Just what I was going to say

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the tables in the same format. This is due to the simplification of the original problem.

Comment: @Stefan Do not need to be the same format.I mean the query output have same format can do the trick.Like your tables all have 10 more columns but all you care is `id` and `value`.